# An undiscovered Minecraft recipe? Can it be?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been reading the [Minefold blog](http://blog.minefold.com/) and therein found the following:

> During a fireside interview at the [Game Developers Conference](http://schedule.gdconf.com/session/13473382/A_Fireside_Chat_with_Markus_%27Notch%27_Persson) in San Francisco last weeek, Minecraft creator Notch dropped an extremely big surprise on the Minecraft community.
>
> **There is still one hidden recipe that has yet to be found.**
>
> It’s hard to believe with all the modding and customization that has been a core feature of the hit indie title hasn’t revealed this mysterious unknown crafting recipe.

Comment: I'm so tempted to edit the title of this into: "An undiscovered minceraft recipe? Can it be?"

Comment: @Rapida: I had to read your comment several times before I got it... touché!

Comment: me to, but i guess you already changed it before i read the comment.

Comment: @mrminecraft3000 It wasn't changed - Rapida said Min **ce** raft, not Min **ec** raft. I had to look a few times myself!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The secret wasn't a recipe:

Here is Notch talking about it on reddit:

> We've tried adding secrets to the game before. Small things, like obscure crafting recipes or weird behavior, and everything always gets figured out immediately. No matter how obscure we make a new feature, it's fully documented within hours of a new release. This is awesome, and a great example of how dedicated some Minecraft players are, but it also means we can't really hide anything good in the game even if we tried.
>   So a while ago, I did some intentionally obscure code in the title screen to switch two letters around, making it say "Minceraft" (old running gag, there's even a "minceraft" mockup t shirt design we did) instead of "Minecraft" on every 10000th game launch or so, and nobody found it! I was so happy about that, I finally knew something about the game the players didn't know.
>
> Flash forward to this GDC a few days ago, I'm doing an interview with Chris Hecker, and he asks me if there's anything nobody has found in the game, and I say yes. I should've said no, but I said yes. Then I start getting emails and tweets about it, people start getting excited, and knowing how minor the secret is, I try to tell people it's a very minor secret. That seems to fuel the flames. A reporter from a well known gaming site wants to run an article on it, and I tell him not to. Getting people hyped up about an intentional typo isn't really a good way to spend everyone's time.
>   There's a lot of cool stuff to learn from this, though. One is that it IS possible to hide stuff in plain sight, but once people go looking for it, they will find it. Another thing is that people seem to want to get excited over things, even if you tell them it's nothing major.
>
> I'm impressed and relieved you found it. I won't comment on it outside of this subreddit.

Source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/qqenq/minceraft_a_post_mortem/) and [Planet Minecraft](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/the-minecraft-secret-is-this-it/)

Comment: ive seen the title on minecraft but saying minceraft. i thought it was a mistake!!